# asp.net regex mixture of letters and numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to have a mixture of letters and numbers for product code in my ASP.Net project. It should have a mixture of 4 uppercase letters and 3 numbers for example,
**A1B2C3D, ABCD123, A123BCD**.

I did this but its not working

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
         ControlToValidate="ProductCode" ErrorMessage="Must be 7 characters in length and a mixture of 4 uppercase characters and 3 numerals " ForeColor="Red" 
         ValidationExpression="/^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){4}[^A-Z]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){3}\D*$)[A-Z\d]{7}$/"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

So how can I get it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the `/`? Chances are that it is not necessary (and would be wrong to include).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the delimiters `/`:

```
ValidationExpression="^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){4}[^A-Z]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){3}\D*$)[A-Z\d]{7}$">
```

The example in documentation of [RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.validationexpression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have `/`, so it is wrong to include them in your regex.

You may want to change `\d` and `\D` to `[0-9]` and `[^0-9]`. If the content is validated on the server side, it probably will go through `Regex` class, where `\d` and `\D` by default works on Unicode characters.